# Java UI thread freezing despite code being in separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm running some webcam captures in a thread like so:

```
class Capture implements Runnable { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            //capture images
            //sleep 5 seconds
    }
}
//To actually start the capture
new Capture().run();
```

I'm doing this constantly, so I expect to still be able to perform UI functions like clicking on buttons while this is going on, but that's not the case. The x button on my JFrame is unresponsive, and same with other UI components.

Do I need to do something other than just using a separate thread? Doesn't seem to be working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just implemented `Runnable`. You haven't started a `Thread` to do the job. Try this:

```
new Thread(new Capture()).start();
```

Also consider [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class for such job.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Knew I was missing something simple; thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are calling the run method but not starting the Thread when you do `new Capture().run();`  you are not even creating an instance of the Thread

> *Do I need to do something other than just using a separate thread?*

yes, create and start the thread doing  instead

```
new Thread(new Capture()).start();
```

Comment: `new Capture().start();` this will result in compilation error as Capture does not extends `Thread`.